# Problem with Tutorial About Making a Python .pyx File

Tags: python, makefile, cython, pyx

I've looked for every possible way to create a `.pyx` file from saving a `.py` file. I followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ltkisc5lz8). However, when I used VSCode, it returned a blank `.pyx` file.

Comment: For those of us who don't want to watch a 17 minute video, can you write down the steps you're actually doing

Comment: I just stuck in first step.I made a python file and it didnot make .pyx file.

Comment: It should just be "save as". A .pyx file is just a text file. If your editor doesn't let you save a text file with a name of your choice then you need a different editor.

Comment: Assuming you still need to ask this question why don't you take screenshots of *every step* that you're taking in your editor when you try to create the file. Maybe someone will be able to tell you where you're going wrong. I don't have vscode so it won't be me.

Comment: It's Fixed! it's fixed by changing the Code Editor.it's Stops me by Changing every Items to  .py file :)

Comment: now I got one more problem that I asked it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759328/i-got-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cython-when-trying-to-make-extensio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To  [davidw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4657412/davidw) it's fixed Just by changing the File name and using the Correct Editor