# I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython' when trying to make Extension

Tags: python, module, cython, cpython

I'm trying to run this code :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
    Extension("sum",  ["a123.pyx"])]

setup(
    name = 'app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

and I got this Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compile.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
```

I'm using Conda and I add cython to it also I'm installing cython in my system.but error doesnot fix!

Comment: You wrote that you installed `Cython`. Did you run something like `pip install Cython` in your command line/terminal?

Comment: yes , I install it on Conda and also I install it With PIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed by uninstall cython in conda and reinstall it Again!

uninstall with :

```
conda uninstall cython
```

reinstall with :

```
conda install -c anaconda cython
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a case that you have installed cython in other conda environment. Make sure that you activate that conda environment in which you installed cython.

```
conda activate installed_env_name
```

Replace "installed_env_name" with your environment name in which you installed cython.

For example if you installed cython in base env, then do this

```
conda activate base
```

It may be a case that you are working in a different conda environment but installed cython in other environment mistakenly. So you need to install cython in your working environment.
So, first activate the env in anaconda prompt :

```
conda activate working_env_name
```

Replace "working_env_name" with your working environment name.
Then install cython

```
pip install cython
```

Futher, if you are using spyder from anaconda, make sure you launch spyder from the environment in which cython is installed.

Comment: I did it and it did nothing.I got this after it.Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.29.21)

Comment: Use command "pip list" in anaconda prompt and you will see the entire list of packages installed. Make sure that Cython is present. Before this, make sure to activate the conda environment you are using to run compile.py